# Correct way to create a new RxJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my Angular 12 webapp...

EDIT:

I try to make this question more understandable and concise. If I fail, you can find the details in the original question below.

SHORT VERSION:
...I need to join data from different sources with a logic that can't be implemented with simple `where` clauses, so I need to write code in a service in order to fetch input data, join them applying the logic and output correct results. That leads my service to subscribe to `Observable` instances in order to get the input, but that's bad practice. Any way out?

LONG VERSION:
... I have two services, among other things.
The first is `BoatService` and it is backed by a simple hard-coded js array (for the time being). It offers a method to get a list of all available boats.

```
export class SailBoat {
  
  constructor(public id: string, 
              public maxBookingsPerDay: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.maxBookingsPerDay = maxBookingsPerDay;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BoatService {

  public static sailboat1 = new SailBoat("SB1", 2);
  public static sailboat2 = new SailBoat("SB2", 2);

  private boats: BehaviorSubject<Boat[]>;

  constructor() { 
    const sbarr = Array();
    sbarr.push(BoatService.sailboat1, BoatService.sailboat2);
    this.boats = new BehaviorSubject<Boat[]>(sbarr);
  }

  public getSailboats(): Observable<Boat[]> {
    return this.boats;
  }
}
```

In its current form it will always emit the same array, but the plan is to move that data into a database sometimes in the near future. Please note that each `SailBoat` has a maximum number of bookings per day (2 in this case).

The other service is `BookingService` and it provides a method to list all bookable boats for a specified day. A boat is bookable for any day if and only if it hasn't already been booked the maximum times for that boat for that day.

Bookings are being stored in a Firebase instance, but SailBoats may be stored in a different database even in the future, when they will be moved off the static JS array.

I'm trying to write the `getAvailableForBooking` function. My idea is to use the `availableForBooking` map (see below) to store the `Observable` instances I lazily create when someone calls this function. That map is indexed by the day string in the form `yyyyMMdd`. The values in the map are the `Observable` (actually `BehaviorSubject`) instances that the caller receives and that provide the available sailboats array.

When someone books a sailboat for a day (i.e. inserts a new `Booking` into the Firebase collection), the corresponding `Observable` (not the AngularFirestore one, but the one I lazily created) should emit a new array of available boats that reflects the new availability of sailboats.

And here is where things get complicated for me. In order to create the array of bookable boats on any day I need to join the array of all the boats and the array of the bookings already placed for that day. I think this is pure business logic, so I assume this has to be done inside a service. However both of that data come in the form of `Observable<...>`,and services should never subscribe, because they will never have a chance to unsubscribe.

```
export class Booking {
    public id: string;
    public sailboatId: string;
    public iso8601: string;
}

export interface IAvailableForBooking {
  [yyyyMMdd: string] : BehaviorSubject<Array<SailBoat>>;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookingService {

  private availableForBooking: IAvailableForBooking;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private boatSvc: BoatService) {}
  
  // [...] here there are a few functions used below, then:

  public getBookingsOn(iso8601day: string): Observable<Booking[]> {
    const startOfDay = dayjs(iso8601day).startOf('day').format();
    const endOfDay = dayjs(iso8601day).endOf('day').format();
    return this.afs.collection<any> // .... and the rest
  }

  public getAvailableForBooking(iso8601day: string): Observable<SailBoat[]> {
    const mapkey = BookingService.getYyyyMMdd(iso8601day);
    const allBoats = this.boatSvc.getSailboats();
    const alreadyBooked = this.getBookingsOn(iso8601day);
    const subscription = alreadyBooked.subscribe( // DANG!!! I need to subscribe inside a service!!
```

What's the correct/best/recommended way to implement this kind of business logic?

Comment: That is a lot of details to process. The more you're concise and try to come up with a minal version of what you're trying to achieve, the more likely you are to get many and good answers

Comment: If I understood right, my question is: why are you trying to handle all this logic in the FE? Second, Subscribing in a service - as you pointed out - is not a great thing to do, so maybe an external class that gets implemented in a Component would help you.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi where am I supposed to handle all this logic, since I have different data sources and no backend except Firebase?
maxime1992 if you look at my code is not that much more than minimal, I've already stripped almost everything not needed for my question